# Autoloading classes defined in module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having probems autoloading classes defined within module. Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/"]
```

*lib/metrics_module.rb*

```
module MetricsModule
  class Metrics
  end

  class BaseMetrics
  end
end
```

*lib/metrics/server_metrics.rb*

```
module MetricsModule
  class ServerMetrics < BaseMetrics
  end
end
```

I'm trying to use it in my code as such

```
  def new_s_to_s_metrics(platform_type)
    return ServerMetrics.new(self, platform_type)
  end
```

But I land up with this error -:

> error updating Mongo Precomputation Data. Error is Unable to autoload constant ServerMetrics, expected /webapps/tensile/lib/metrics/server_metrics.rb to define it

**Update**

After moving the files to a new folder `metrics_module`, here is what happened: I followed what you said, and this is where I ended up

```
Error updating Mongo Precomputation Data. Error is Unable to autoload constant AfMetrics, expected     
/webapps/adwyzeupstream/lib/metrics_module/af_metrics.rb to define it
/webapps/adwyzeupstream/lib/tasks/helper.rake:30:in `rescue in timed_task'
/webapps/adwyzeupstream/lib/tasks/helper.rake:37:in `timed_task'
/webapps/adwyzeupstream/lib/tasks/precomputation.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant AfMetrics, expected /webapps/adwyzeupstream/lib/metrics_module/af_metrics.rb to define it
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/pratikbothra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
```

Code is like

*lib/metrics_module/af_metrics.rb*

```
module MetricsModule
  class AfMetrics < BaseMetrics
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be successfully autoloaded, the class is to be located in the file with a name, following Rails conventions.

**TL;DR**:

```
mkdir lib/metrics_module
mv lib/metrics/server_metrics.rb lib/metrics_module/server_metrics.rb
```

The name convention is: nested class’ file name is to be constructed as `top_module/nested_module/class_name.rb` where `top_module`, `nested_module` and `class_name` are snake-cased names of respective modules/classes.

In your case Rails tries to autoload `class Metrics::ServerMetrics` from `metrics/server_metrics.rb` and looks up for `class MetricsModule::ServerMetrics` in [inexisting] `metrics_module/server_metrics.rb` and therefore fails.

Comment: And within the file server_metrics, no need to require metrics_module.rb as rails will do that for you?

Comment: And vica_versa as well, within a model, I don't need to require metrics_module etc, it will get auto required?

Comment: Since the path is included in `autoload` and naming conventions are met, everything will be autoloaded, yes.

Comment: I updated my answer, the error did change, but I don't know why it changed to this.....Am I loading the files right in config.autoload_paths? Your answer makes complete sense, fyi, but the error is almost baffling to me.

Comment: It looks like in `lib/tasks/helper.rake:30` you address `AfMetrics` without it’s namespace. Try to address it as `MetricsModule::AfMetrics`.